Cors bug with codepen demo implementing
I have server allowed CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // console.log("HOSTING SERVER PREVENT OTHER DOMAINS+")
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

From headers :
accept-ranges:
bytes
cache-control:
public, max-age=0
connection:
keep-alive
content-length:
1216345
content-type:
application/x-tgif
date:
Fri, 01 Nov 2024 19:31:32 GMT
etag:
W/"128f59-18abe372ca9"
keep-alive:
timeout=5
last-modified:
Fri, 22 Sep 2023 18:46:41 GMT
x-powered-by:
Express
accept:
*/*
accept-encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
accept-language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control:
no-cache
connection:
keep-alive
dnt:
1
host:
maximumroulette.com
origin:
https://cdpn.io
pragma:
no-cache
referer:
https://cdpn.io/
sec-ch-ua:
"AVG Secure Browser";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"
sec-ch-ua-mobile:
?0
sec-ch-ua-platform:
"Windows"
sec-fetch-dest:
empty
sec-fetch-mode:
cors
sec-fetch-site:
cross-site
user-agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 AVG/129.0.0.0

Any suggestion ?
